# BubbleSort with user input c#

Tags: c#, user-input, bubble-sort

I'm creating a program that lets a user input different salespeople and depending on items they've sold they get a specific level. Im now trying to create a BubbleSort for the console to print the "salespeople" in order after how many items they've sold. How do I write the array based on the items they've input earlier?

Im new in coding and would'nt mind feedback on my current code on what I can do better.

Thanks in advance! Putting my code down below

```
namespace salesprogram
```

{
class SalesPerson
{
public string name;
public ulong number;
public string district;
public int items;

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SalesPerson.InputSalesPersons();
        int[] arr = {};
        bubbleSort(arr);

        
    }


    public static void InputSalesPersons()
    {
        Console.Write("Hur många säljare vill du mata in? ");
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        var sellers = new List<SalesPerson>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            SalesPerson s = RegisterPerson(i);
            sellers.Add(s);
        }
    }
        
    static SalesPerson RegisterPerson(int i)
    {
        
        // Sätter en string för namn på säljare
        Console.Write("Ange namn för säljare {0}: ", i);
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        

        // String för personnummer 
        Console.Write("Ange personnummer för säljare {0} (10 siffror): ", i);
        ulong number = ulong.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // String för distrikt på säljare
        Console.Write("Ange distrikt för säljare {0}: ", i);
        string district = Console.ReadLine();

        // String för sålda artiklar
        Console.Write("Ange antal sålda artiklar för säljare {0}: ", i);
        int items = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

       
        SalesPerson s = new SalesPerson(name, number, district, items);
        return s;

        

    }

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length - i - 1; j++)
            {
                if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
                {
                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public SalesPerson(string name, ulong number, string district, int items)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.district = district;
        this.items = items;
    }

    // Beroende på antal sålda artiklar (items) får säljarna en nivå (Level)
    public int Level
    {
        get
        {
            if (items < 50) return 1;
            if (items < 100) return 2;
            if (items < 200) return 3;
            return 4;
        }
        
    }

   

}
```

}

Comment: I wonder if whoever upvoted this question can explain what "How do I write the array based on the items they've input earlier" means.

Comment: What have you tried? There appears to be no code for writing the input?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd recommend:
Keep your main clean. There should be no  logic.
Move your logic to method into `SalesPerson`;

Also `SalesPerson` should be in separate file.

You use `SalesPerson`like a service. It should be `static class`
with static method named like `InputSalesPersons`. `InputSalesPersons` rename to `RegisterPerson`.

Use `var` it's a good practies.

The better way to convert it use `Parse` and `TryParse` methods

`InputSalesPersons`will have the next code.

```
public static void InputSalesPersons()
{
        Console.Write("Hur många säljare vill du mata in? ");
        var count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var sellers = new List<SalesPerson>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            SalesPerson s = RegisterPerson(i);
            sellers.Add(s);
        }
}
```

You will get clean `Main`. Is beauty, isn't it?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        SalesPerson.InputSalesPersons();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How would implement the "Level" and make a bubblesort out of the input I've gotten from "items". I've tried this but I can not reach/use the int "level". I edited the question so you can see what I've tried.